# Not Equals In Where Clause Uses Filesort, But Equals Doesn't. Why?

Tags: mysql

I'm revamping my site's inner-mail system, and I came across something I don't understand. Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `mails` (
    `id` bigint(12) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `recipient_id` mediumint(8) unsigned not null,
    `date_sent` datetime not null,
    `status` enum('unread', 'read', 'deleted') default 'unread',
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    INDEX(`recipient_id`, `status`, `date_sent`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`recipient_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `mail_contents` (
    `mail_id` bigint(12) unsigned not null,
    `sender_id` mediumint(8) unsigned not null,
    `subject` varchar(150) default '',
    `content` text not null,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`mail_id`) REFERENCES `mails` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mails AS m
LEFT JOIN mail_contents AS mc ON mc.mail_id = m.id
WHERE recipient_id = 66
AND status != 'deleted'
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
LIMIT 40\G
```

An EXPLAIN on the query shows "Using where; Using index; Using filesort". However if I change the query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mails AS m
LEFT JOIN mail_contents AS mc ON mc.mail_id = m.id
WHERE recipient_id = 66
AND status = 'sent'
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
LIMIT 40\G
```

The EXPLAIN shows "Using where; Using index". For some reason using != in the first query causes a filesort, but using = in the second query doesn't use a filesort. I'm curious about what's going on under the hood that would cause the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equals is inclusive and != is exclusive. It's more efficient for MySQL to find inclusive results.

The "Using filesort" is actually negative in this case, because it means that the query requires use of a temporary table to *sort* (the table being the *file*) and then return the result..

Comment: I always assume filesort is negative. I was curious why inclusive and exclusive operators would make such a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `INDEX(recipient_id, status, date_sent)` is used in the second query for sorting, because the first 2 columns are fixed, and the order by is using the 3rd one `date_sent` => no `filesort`

It can not be used in the first query because `status` is not constant (`!= 'deleted'`).

More informations here:[*ORDER BY Optimization*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)